# unable to pause my Repository execution using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net MVC-4 web application. now inside my model repository class i want to pause the execution of it for testing purposes . so inside my repository model class , i define the following inside the repository model class:-

```
 public class Repository
{

        public TechnologyAudit IntiateTechnologyAudit(int actionId, int typeID, string username)
        {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

and i am calling the repository method from my controller class as follow:-

```
repository.IntiateTechnologyAudit(actionid,typeid,"Test User");
```

but this did not pause the repository execution for the specified time.. so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: We need a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you. Just one line of code is not enough.

Comment: What does "pause the repository" mean? Each request is executed on a different thread. Freezing one will only dealy the specific request

Comment: @ScottChamberlain please check my edit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to pause the execution for certain amount of time,, to test how external system behave during the execution...

Comment: u can try to debug and verify in "Thread Window" if this thread is getting a sleep

Comment: @JohnG and? What *doesn't* work? What did you expect and what did you observe? Your call *will* block any request that calls the `Audit` method for 10 seconds. It won't prevent the *application* from receiving new requests nor block requests that don't call `Audit`